# Django roll-up (collapsible) menu

Tags: python, django, menu

I have a web app with three frames (banner, menu, content)
The menu frame needs to have a dynamic roll-up menu
Example:

```
+ Teachers
  - Create
  - Edit
  - Delete

+ Schools
  - Create
  - Edit
  - Delete
  - View Staff

+ Classrooms
  - Create
  - Edit
  - Delete
```

If you click on the + or "Schools" it will hide/un-hide items under it. 
The menu needs to be dynamically drawn after user login based on user group and role.
Some users may only be authorized to see

```
+ Classrooms
  -Edit
```

and some users will see everything.

Is there anything built or a plugin that anyone has used that would provide a framework for what I need?

Comment: for rolling menu (which is done by JS not django) or for management and rendering menu?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simple implementation using jQuery:

```
<div id="menu">
    <a>Teachers</a><br />
    <div style="display: none">
        <a href="">Edit</a><br />
        <a href="">Delete</a><br /> 
    </div>
    <a>Schools</a><br />
    <div style="display: none">
        <a href="">Edit</a><br />
        <a href="">Delete</a><br /> 
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#menu > a').click(function(){
    $(this).next().next().slideToggle();
    return false;
});
</script>
```

Comment: `$(this).next().next()` - dont forget about `<br/>` :)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe here (for django):
http://www.google.pl/search?q=django+tree+menu 
and here (for js)
http://www.google.pl/search?q=javascript+tree+menu 
or better here (jQuery)
http://www.google.pl/search?q=jquery+tree+menu

Anyway, for simple cases, its not too hard to make your own impl.